# How to insert data from a SQL SELECT into a spreadsheet

Tags: python, sql

I am having trouble writing the result of my `SELECT` statement into an excel sheet using `xlrd`.

I have been able to figure out how to add a new excel row per data row, using:

```
>>> for row_number, info in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
        sheet.write(row_number, info)
```

But how would I also move over a cell (column) for each new data input? Or do I have to manually specify all 25 of my columns here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
for number, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    for column, cell in enumerate(row):
        sheet.write(number, column, cell)
```